# slow or failed writing image vector to *.gif with magick in R?

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have a vector of 31 images, each 2400x1640 pixels, and about 900kB each when written out to *.png. I'm trying to convert them to a *.gif with the magick package in R.

```
    img <- c(im1, im2, im3, im4, im5, im6, im7, im8, im9, im10, im11, im12, im13, im14, im15, im16, 
        im17, im18, im19, im20, im21, im22, im23, im24, im25, im26, im27, im28, im29, im30, im31)

    move <- image_animate(img, fps = 1, dispose = "previous")
    image_write_gif(move, "movie.gif")
```

returns an unusably bad quality video.

```
    image_write(move, "movie.gif")
```

runs slow to the point of crashing R, on a nearly brand new machine with 32 gigs of usable RAM. I'm trying to understand what's wrong here and how to fix it. Doesn't seem like it should be still running (or non-responsive?) after 15 or 20 minutes. Am I wrong? Should it be this slow? Or is there something wrong with my method?

ETA: It does finish after about 45 minutes, but I have to believe there's a better way.

Comment: How big are your images? You may be threshing between RAM and disk if you are running out of RAM. What does your policy.xml file say about file size and dimensions, etc. You may need to allocate more resources to your process. Also gif quantization from >256 colors to 256 or less colors is time consuming. You might try using a common color map and apply that to each frame. See -remap.

Comment: I think they are not big images - they're simple line drawings produced by a scientific program.  I'm not sure of the size of the image object in the R environment, but if I image_write(im) for a single image (they are all the same size) it produces a *.png that's only 900 KB.  I wondered if it might be a resource allocation problem but I honestly have no idea how to find policy.xml and Google is not super helpful on that point.

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php